# Cannot load some DNX projects from Git

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I was willing to have a look at the AspNetCore Identity Framework, which is published on [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity)

After downloading this project, I do have an error when opening it in Visual Studio 2015.

some of the projects does open, while others yield the following error in the output:

[image: error screenshot]

> C:\Dev\External\Identity\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.xproj
>   : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets

Any idea what's wrong and how this particular issue can be resolved?

Comment: What VS version do you use and what branch do you clone?

Comment: I just clone the "master" repo, or a recent tag, which means that it's written on .NET Core.